# How to install an X11 server without running a desktop environment

Tags: ssh, gui, x11-forwarding

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS and would like to be able to serve X11 applications over SSH without a desktop environment running on the server.  I'm able to configure X11 forwarding and run programs without issue by installing my GUI application, enabling X11 forwarding in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and running an X11 client on my local machine.  The problem is this always seems to automatically bring in a ton of packages, essentially turning my server into a normal Ubuntu Desktop environment with GNOME and everything.

Is there a way to just install the X11 server and not install a full desktop environment?  Alternatively, is there a way to install everything as I have been, but disable the desktop environment and only run the X11 server?

Thanks!

Comment: Think "Display server" when you have an X server.  The server machine you are sshing into needs only X clients, no X server needed.

Comment: @ubfan1 Does that mean I don't need to install any xorg packages?  I get the following message when trying to run feh for example: `feh ERROR: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derp.  Apparently the only package needed for what I described is `xauth`.  Thanks @ubfan1 for pointing out my misunderstanding regarding X11 servers vs clients.